# Expecting ValueError: too many values to unpack but getting TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 17 2015, 03:50:35) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2**

```
>>> def f():
...   return True
... 
>>> 
>>> a,b = f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

vs

```
>>> def f():
...   return 'True'
... 
>>> 
>>> a,b = f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Why the difference ?

Comment: have you tried `a,b = f(),f()` ?

Comment: Try `def f(): return "Tr"` then call it with `a, b = f()`. In your first example, you can't unpack something non iterable, second example you're trying to unpack an iterable with 4 items into 2.

Comment: Note: Nothing about this is specific to Python 2.7; every version of Python since iterable unpacking was introduced has had the behavior described.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `bool` object are not iterable, even if `bool` object where iterable, it will do the same thing as the second example.

Example:

```
for i in True:
    print(i)
```

Raises and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rep\Desktop\code\so.py", line 3517, in <module>
    for i in True:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

But:

```
for i in 'True':
    print(i)
```

Returns:

```
T
r
u
e
```

And also:

to solve them do:

```
a,b = f(),f()
```

And as @ggorlen says,do:

```
def f(): return "Tr"
```

Then:

```
a, b = f()
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError` means "this sort of object can never be used in this context", while `ValueError` means "some objects of this sort could be used in this context, but this one has the wrong value". In this case, no `bool` can *ever* be iterated (what would it mean to sequentially process a `bool` value by value?), so it's a `TypeError`.

`str` *can* be iterated though. `str` is a sequence of length 1 `str`s representing each character in the string, so `'True'` iterates as `'T'`, `'r'`, `'u'` and `'e'`; a total of four values, but when you need to fill two variables, only `str` of length 2 are valid, and all other `str` have invalid values, thus the `ValueError`. If you'd provided more names to assign to, e.g. `a, b, c, d = f()`, or the string was shorter, e.g. `"Tr"`, the code would have worked without errors.